# OOM with a "simple" ResNet50 using Tensorflow2.0 on an Nvidia RTX2080 Ti

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm surprised to face an Out-of-Memory error using `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50` implementation on an Nvidia RTX2080Ti (with 11Gb of memory !).

### Question:

Is there something wrong with the workflow I use?

### Notes:

- I'm using `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1` with `CUDA v10.1`
- I work on a segmentation task, thus the large `output_shape`
- I build the batches myself, thus the use of `train_on_batch()`
- Even when setting `memory_growth` to `True`, the memory get filled-up from 700Mb to 10850Mb in a fraction of a second.

### Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as ke
import numpy as np

ke.backend.clear_session()

inputs = ke.layers.Input(shape=(512,1024,3), dtype="float32")
outputs = ke.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet")(inputs)
outputs = ke.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.compat.v1.image.resize_bilinear(x, size=(512,1024)))(outputs)
outputs = ke.layers.Conv2D(2, 1, activation="softmax")(outputs)
model = ke.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer=ke.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001), loss=ke.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())

images = np.zeros((1,512,1024,3), dtype=np.float32)
targets = np.zeros((1,512,1024,2), dtype=np.float32)

model.train_on_batch(images, targets)
```

Comment: whats your batch size?

Comment: It's 1. (I'm in "channel_last" data format)

Comment: that's interesting. have you tried reducing the image dimensions ? lets say 64*128 ? just to be sure it's not because of that ?

Comment: yes, the limit is around 700x512 input size…

Comment: okay. i will make that as a answer and please accept it so that its helpful foe future users

Comment: I'm implementing the same in PyTorch. We'll see if it's a limit of the model, or an implementation problem in TF2

Comment: good to try and conclude

Answer (score 0):

Resnet being the complex complex model, the dimensions of the input might be the reason for OOM error. Try reducing the dimensions and the corresponding batch size(as much as the memory can hold) and try.

As mentioned in comments it worked with batch size 1 and with dimensions 700*512.